# PHP MVC admin panel how should we create it?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, admin, panel

I have learned MVC I'm no pro. just learning and improving myself. So my question is how to build an MVC admin panel? Should we separate it or can I use it as I did in the image I uploaded?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCJdN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should in my idea separate it. it will be easier to control for you and your website when someone else does it.